# Ubuntu SDK - chroot errors creating a device kit

Tags: chroot, sdk

No problem in installing the Ubuntu SDK, but when I try to create a device kit this is what happens:

...

...

Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20141019) ...

Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...

173 added, 0 removed; done. Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
done.

Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.26+nmu4ubuntu1) ...

E: 10mount: umount: /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home/zcarlos: target is busy E: 10mount: (In some cases useful info about processes that E: 10mount: use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)

E: click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a: Chroot setup failed: stage=setup-stop umount: /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home/zcarlos: target is busy (In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)

umount:

/var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home: target is busy (In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)

umount:

/var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a: target is busy (In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
Command returned 1: schroot -u root -c source:click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386 -- /finish.sh

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/click", line 86, in sys.exit(main()) File "/usr/bin/click", line 82, in main return mod.run(args) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 266, in run return args.func(parser, args) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 68, in create return chroot.create(args.keep_broken_chroot) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/chroot.py", line 551, in create self.destroy() File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/chroot.py", line 649, in destroy shutil.rmtree(chroot_dir) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 464, in rmtree _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 406, in _rmtree_safe_fd onerror(os.rmdir, fullname, sys.exc_info()) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 404, in _rmtree_safe_fd os.rmdir(name, dir_fd=topfd) OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: 'home'
There was an error creating the click target, cleaning up
umount: /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home/zcarlos: target is busy (In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)

umount:

/var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home: target is busy (In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)

umount:

/var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a: target is busy (In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).) Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/click", line 86, in sys.exit(main()) File "/usr/bin/click", line 82, in main return mod.run(args) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 266, in run return args.func(parser, args) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 91, in destroy return chroot.destroy() File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/chroot.py", line 649, in destroy shutil.rmtree(chroot_dir) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 464, in rmtree _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 406, in _rmtree_safe_fd onerror(os.rmdir, fullname, sys.exc_info()) File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 404, in _rmtree_safe_fd os.rmdir(name, dir_fd=topfd) OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: 'home'

Unmounting /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a

Unmount failed... trying to force

umount: /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a: target is busy (In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
Unmounting /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home
umount: /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home: mountpoint not found
Unmount failed... trying to force
umount:
Unmounting /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home failed Unmounting /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home/zcarlos Unmount failed... trying to force

/var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home: mountpoint not found umount: /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home/zcarlos: mountpoint not found

Unmounting /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home/zcarlos failed Deleting /etc/schroot/chroot.d/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386

umount: /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-c8973184-ca9f-4131-af12-613258b49d8a/home/zcarlos: mountpoint not found

Deleting /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386

click target was removed successfully

---Click exited with errors, please check the output---

My home dir is encrypted. After this message appears, I can't access my home.
The desktop is totally clean. When I open nautilus - no files, only access your private data.desktop. I have to close the session.

The first time I installed the SDK, I was still on 14.10, back then it was possible to create the kit. The only thing was the device never booted.
So I upgraded the system to beta 15.04. Maybe I did something wrong meanwhile.
What can I do to get things working?

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found some relevant bugs on Launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/click/+bug/1427264

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/769595

Following one of the bug comments (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/769595/comments/11), I think I've fixed the problem on my system by opening /etc/schroot/click/fstab and changing the /home line to point to my home directory instead of /home:

Specifically, I changed this line:

```
/home           /home           none    rw,rbind        0       0
```

to this:

```
/home/username  /home/username  none    rw,rbind        0       0
```

with my actual username in place of `username`.

It looks like they're working on a fix for this so that it will just work out of the box for people with encrypted home directories; hopefully it will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps question and answer by hdastwb about different bugs but they both helped me to find solution.

I have `schroot mount error` on Ubuntu 14.04 with `ecryptfs`. Change or comment `/home` in `/etc/schroot/click/fstab` does not take effect.

Switching from `kernel 3.19.0-29-generic` to `3.16.0-50-generic` or `3.13.0-64-generic` solved the problem.

2015-10-16

For me this bug fixed in `schroot` package version `1.6.8-1ubuntu1.1` by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/schroot/+bug/1398523.
Now `schroot` mount works with `ecryptfs` and `kernel 3.19.0-31`.